# .html() in jQuery to fetch an echo from a PHP script

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=button]").click(function () {
        $("#test").html("W3Schools");
        alert("Would submit: " + $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val());
        $.ajax({ url: "index.php",
        data: {action: $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val()},
        type: 'post'
        });
    });
});
```

That 'W3Schools' is obviously just filler, I have a function named 'generateHTML()' in my php script that I'd like to put in place of the 'W3Schools'.  How can I go about this?

Comment: Use the `success` callback to deal with the result http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You set the response you get as content of `#test`... have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Norse, it is.  
Esailija, My questions isn't about how to deal with it, it's how do I fetch the data from a function?  
FelixKling I know that, I'm asking about getting the echo'd html from a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you define that function, use **echo** response instead of **return** response.

So whenever you call $.ajax function, it'll give that response that you can use in html.

**PHP function :**

```
function generateHTML(){
 // code
  echo $response;
}
```

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=button]").click(function () {
        $("#test").html("W3Schools");
        alert("Would submit: " + $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val());
        $.ajax({ url: "index.php",
        data: {action: $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val()},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response){
              $("#test").html(response); // will overwrite the previous HTML of test element
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh god, this is almost so correct, however it copies EVERYTHING, including the search bar!  Is this just because I'm a bad developer?  Or is there some trick to this?

Comment: @Adola yes, don't make a request to php page that responds with a full web page. `ajax` doesn't call PHP functions, it makes a normal request just like you do with normal web browser usage.

Comment: Hah!  You're right, thank you very much, this has been great!  I've been mostly ok with PHP, and struggled a bit with MySQL, but jQuery and Ajax have been an absolute nightmare to me.  Thank you!